# Video Rewarder Ads работает только тестовая реклама

Tags: android, android-studio, видео, admob, ads

При подключении видео рекламы с вознаграждением от AdMob показывается тестовая реклама, но при изменении ее ID она перестает показываться. Метод onRewardedVideoAdFailedToLoad возвращает значение errorcode = 3. Не могу понять в чем проблема.

Вот пример моей реализации :

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.CountDownTimer;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAds;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.reward.RewardItem;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.reward.RewardedVideoAd;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.reward.RewardedVideoAdListener;

/**
 * Main Activity. Inflates main activity xml and implements RewardedVideoAdListener.
 */
public class VideoAds extends AppCompatActivity implements RewardedVideoAdListener {
    private static final String AD_UNIT_ID = "ca-app-pub-1004492264679075/5879089208";
    private static final String APP_ID = "ca-app-pub-1004492264679075~8530141653";
    private static final long COUNTER_TIME = 10;
    private static final int GAME_OVER_REWARD = 1;

    private int mCoinCount;
    private TextView mCoinCountText;
    private CountDownTimer mCountDownTimer;
    private boolean mGameOver;
    private boolean mGamePaused;
    private RewardedVideoAd mRewardedVideoAd;
    private Button mRetryButton;
    private Button mShowVideoButton;
    private long mTimeRemaining;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_video_ads);

        //Initialize the Mobile Ads SDK.
        MobileAds.initialize(getApplicationContext(), APP_ID);

        mRewardedVideoAd = MobileAds.getRewardedVideoAdInstance(getApplicationContext());
        mRewardedVideoAd.setRewardedVideoAdListener(this);
        loadRewardedVideoAd();

        // Create the "retry" button, which tries to show an interstitial between game plays.
        mRetryButton = findViewById(R.id.retry_button);
        mRetryButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        mRetryButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                startGame();
            }
        });

        // Create the "show" button, which shows a rewarded video if one is loaded.
        mShowVideoButton = findViewById(R.id.show_video_button);
        mShowVideoButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        mShowVideoButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                showRewardedVideo();
            }
        });

        // Display current coin count to user.
        mCoinCountText = findViewById(R.id.coin_count_text);
        mCoinCount = 0;
        mCoinCountText.setText("Coins: " + mCoinCount);

        startGame();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        pauseGame();
        mRewardedVideoAd.pause(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if (!mGameOver && mGamePaused) {
            resumeGame();
        }
        mRewardedVideoAd.resume(this);
    }

    private void pauseGame() {
        mCountDownTimer.cancel();
        mGamePaused = true;
    }

    private void resumeGame() {
        createTimer(mTimeRemaining);
        mGamePaused = false;
    }

    private void loadRewardedVideoAd() {
        if (!mRewardedVideoAd.isLoaded()) {
            mRewardedVideoAd.loadAd(AD_UNIT_ID, new AdRequest.Builder().build());
        }
    }

    private void addCoins(int coins) {
        mCoinCount += coins;
        mCoinCountText.setText("Coins: " + mCoinCount);
    }

    private void startGame() {
        // Hide the retry button, load the ad, and start the timer.
        mRetryButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        mShowVideoButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        loadRewardedVideoAd();
        createTimer(COUNTER_TIME);
        mGamePaused = false;
        mGameOver = false;
    }

    // Create the game timer, which counts down to the end of the level
    // and shows the "retry" button.
    private void createTimer(long time) {
        final TextView textView = findViewById(R.id.timer);
        if (mCountDownTimer != null) {
            mCountDownTimer.cancel();
        }
        mCountDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(time * 1000, 50) {
            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUnitFinished) {
                mTimeRemaining = ((millisUnitFinished / 1000) + 1);
                textView.setText("seconds remaining: " + mTimeRemaining);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                if (mRewardedVideoAd.isLoaded()) {
                    mShowVideoButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
                textView.setText("You Lose!");
                addCoins(GAME_OVER_REWARD);
                mRetryButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                mGameOver = true;
            }
        };
        mCountDownTimer.start();
    }

    private void showRewardedVideo() {
        mShowVideoButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        if (mRewardedVideoAd.isLoaded()) {
            mRewardedVideoAd.show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRewardedVideoAdLeftApplication() {
        Toast.makeText(this, "onRewardedVideoAdLeftApplication", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onRewardedVideoAdClosed() {
        Toast.makeText(this, "onRewardedVideoAdClosed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        // Preload the next video ad.
        loadRewardedVideoAd();
    }

    @Override
    public void onRewardedVideoAdFailedToLoad(int errorCode) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "onRewardedVideoAdFailedToLoad (" + String.valueOf(errorCode) + ")", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onRewardedVideoAdLoaded() {
        Toast.makeText(this, "onRewardedVideoAdLoaded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onRewardedVideoAdOpened() {
        Toast.makeText(this, "onRewardedVideoAdOpened", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onRewarded(RewardItem reward) {
        Toast.makeText(this,
                String.format(" onRewarded! currency: %s amount: %d", reward.getType(),
                        reward.getAmount()),
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        addCoins(reward.getAmount());
    }

    @Override
    public void onRewardedVideoStarted() {
        Toast.makeText(this, "onRewardedVideoStarted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Ответ - errorcode = 3 означает, что с код не содержит ошибок, но в AdMob не существует ролика для данного запроса. Эта ошибка возникает если аккаунт в AdMob не активирован, или создан недавно. Обычно после получения id нужно подождать несколько часов прежде чем аккаунт будет активирован и начнет возвращать ролики по запросам.

Comment: Под активацией аккаунта Вы понимаете получение письма от Google с пин-кодом и ввод его в специальную форму? Просто рекламный видео блок я создал уже давно (около месяца назад),однако он не показывается до сих пор.

Comment: Ваш код работает корректно, проверял со своим ключем. Скорей всего проблема на стороне AdMob. Как вариант, попробуйте загружать рекламу принудительно, без проверки - if (!mRewardedVideoAd.isLoaded()). Не знаю почему, но иногда этот метод возвращает true даже если реклама не загружена.

Comment: Исправил, но реклама вновь не загружается. Попробую активировать аккаунт и после активации напишу заработала ли реклама.

Comment: Братан , решил проблему? У меня то же самое. Банеры и межстраничные работают отлично, но за вознаграждение только тестовый id. Ни как не могу решить эту проблему.

Answer (score 1):

Добавь в  build.gradle

```
dependencies {    
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:19.5.0'
}
```

Без него Rewarded не работает.